# Button not opening another HTML file after clicking check box

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to get my Terms and Service conditions **HTML** page to have a checkbox with a button that opens the next page (another **HTML** page) only if check box is checked. When I check the check box the continue button doesn't load next page. Even if the checkbox is unchecked it does not load the next page.

```html
<h2>Terms and Service</h2>
<div class="ex3">
      My conditions and terms.................................
</div>
<script>
    document.querySelector('.checkbox').checked
</script>

<form>
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" required>I agree to all Terms and Conditions</br>
</form>

<button onclick="other_page.html">Click</button>
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: For a future post, only relevant code and the thing you are asking is already on the google or any other StackOverflow question just try to research what's the main issue

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons why this code isn't working.

Firstly, the `onclick` handler doesn't work like that. It executes JavaScript code within it, so you could just redirect with a simple

```
<button onclick="window.location='other_page.html'">Click</button>
```

but you need it to be conditional. So you would call a JavaScript function to do that.

```js
var redirectIfClicked = function () {
  // check if the checkbox is checked
  var isChecked = document.querySelector('.checkbox').checked
  // If it is then we can redirect using window.location
  if (isChecked) {
    window.location = 'other_page.html'
  } else {
    // it isnt checked so don't do anything (or do something else)
    console.log('Dont do anything')
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Terms and Service</h2>
<div class="ex3">
      My conditions and terms.................................
</div>

<form>
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" required />I agree to all Terms and Conditions
</form>

<button onclick="redirectIfClicked()">Click</button>
```

The code above is ran when the button is clicked. It first checks if the checkbox is checked. If it is, then it redirects to your chosen page. If it isn't then it does nothing.

Secondly, this does nothing:

```
<script>
    document.querySelector('.checkbox').checked
</script>
```

This returns true or false, so your code effectively becomes

```
<script>
  true
</script>
```

You aren't doing anything with this and it wouldn't work even if you did because you aren't waiting for the DOM to be loaded.